# Get points in a radius that exclude point from a smaller radius on UE4.27

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Hello I am making a game with AI on Unreal Engine 4.27 that attacks you and I implemented a ticket system to prevent them from all attacking at the same time. The problem is that I want those that are not attacking to roam around the player until they get a ticket but I also want them to stay out of the attack range to not disturb those who have a ticket and are attacking me. So in short I would like to get random points in a radius that exclude another smaller radius that have for center my player. Any idea ?

I first tried with the getrandompointsInNavigableRadius function but I wasn't satisfied with the result as stated previously, the AI were bothering each other. I tried searching on google but I only found mathematic solution that i don't understand and don't know how to translate on Unreal

Comment: Welcome.  Please edit your question to include the code you are using.  Screenshots of the behaviour tree and any decorators code and any BP referencing the "ticket" system, would be helpful. to allowing a solution.